# Ошибка Assets\Samples\2D Animation\6.0.1\Samples\5 SpriteSwap\Scripts\Runtime\RuntimeSwap.cs(28,17): error CS0246

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый день я не совсем новичок, но и не профессионал. Я делал игру и вдруг проект перестал запускаться и выдает ошибку Unity Editor не много посидел и запустил, перезагрузил пакеты и консоль кидает 5 ошибок:

1. Assets\Samples\2D Animation\6.0.1\Samples\5 SpriteSwap\Scripts\Runtime\RuntimeSwap.cs(28,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SpriteLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. Assets\Samples\2D Animation\6.0.1\Samples\5 SpriteSwap\Scripts\Runtime\SwapFullSkin.cs(10,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SpriteLibraryAsset' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3. Assets\Samples\2D Animation\6.0.1\Samples\5 SpriteSwap\Scripts\Runtime\SwapFullSkin.cs(11,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SpriteLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4. Assets\Samples\2D Animation\6.0.1\Samples\5 SpriteSwap\Scripts\Runtime\SwapPart.cs(14,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SpriteResolver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
5. Assets\Samples\2D Animation\6.0.1\Samples\5 SpriteSwap\Scripts\Runtime\SwapPart.cs(20,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SpriteLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Я даже не знаю как их устранить, я впервые сталкиваюсь с таким, пожалуйста помогите решить данную проблему

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что не может найти класс, на который вы ссылаетесь. Можете добавить часть кода (хотя бы строку по одной из ошибок), на которую жалуется

Comment: Можно хотя-бы пример для одной из ошибок? А то не совсем понимаю что нужно писать

Comment: А я не понимаю, что не так. У вас ошибка на ссылается на какую-то строку. Например первая ссылается на строку 28 скрипта RuntimeSwap. Вы можете добавить эту строку в вопрос, чтобы было понятно, на что конкретно жалуется?

Comment: Спасибо за то что откликнулся на мой вопрос, но я запорол проект так что он теперь вообще не запускается